# how to read google analytics api?

Tags: google-analytics

ok lets say we have a return like

```
  0 => 
    object(gapiReportEntry)[7]
      private 'metrics' => 
        array
          'pageviews' => int 1
          'uniquePageviews' => int 1
      private 'dimensions' => 
        array
          'visitCount' => string '61' (length=2)
          'source' => string '(direct)' (length=8)
          'city' => string 'Jakarta' (length=7)
          'pagePath' => string '/netcoid' (length=8)
          'date' => string '20110511' (length=8)
  1 => 
    object(gapiReportEntry)[12]
      private 'metrics' => 
        array
          'pageviews' => int 1
          'uniquePageviews' => int 1
      private 'dimensions' => 
        array
          'visitCount' => string '68' (length=2)
          'source' => string 'github.com' (length=10)
          'city' => string 'Jakarta' (length=7)
          'pagePath' => string '/netcoid' (length=8)
          'date' => string '20110511' (length=8)
  2 => 
    object(gapiReportEntry)[8]
      private 'metrics' => 
        array
          'pageviews' => int 31
          'uniquePageviews' => int 1
      private 'dimensions' => 
        array
          'visitCount' => string '57' (length=2)
          'source' => string '(direct)' (length=8)
          'city' => string 'Jakarta' (length=7)
          'pagePath' => string '/netcoid' (length=8)
          'date' => string '20110510' (length=8)
```

i assume that i can read it like this,

0 = >

- there is one page view ( means that the visitor doenst view the page again )
- there is one uniqpage view
- 61 visitcount ? ok from where ? who ? on day 20110511 there is 61 visit count ? to /netcod from the **same** source ? ( direct ) from the **same** city ? but there is olny one uniqpage view? what does this mean?

ok. lets say i can explain it.

question is

1.**how can we explain exactly what is going on ? how do you read this ?**

2.**what is diffrence between metrics and dimensions ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dimension is an attribute of something you're reporting on. A metric is a statistic that relates to the attribute. For example, in a report that shows pageviews for each referral source broken down by date, source and date are dimensions and pageviews is the metric.

If you're familiar with SQL you can think of it in terms of dimensions being what goes in the `GROUP BY` clause while metrics are the calculations that go into the aggregation functions such as `SUM`.

The extract you have from the GA API is showing you the `pageviews` and `uniquePageviews` that relate to each grouping of `visitCount`, `source`, `city`, `pagePath` and `date`.